# Is every complex root of an integer polynomial a product of an algebraic real number and a root of unity?

Tags: roots-of-unity, algebraic-numbers

If $f \in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $u \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of $f$, then do we always have that $u = a\xi$ where $a$ is some real algebraic number, and $\xi$ is some root of unity?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Quick answer: the absolute value of an algebraic number is algebraic. However, the argument is almost never commensurable with $\pi$. For instance, take $u = \frac{3}{5}+ i \frac{4}{5}$.